# Django Auth with LDAP and Local Accounts

Tags: python, django, ldap

I currently have Django and LDAP working. However, I want to limit LDAP authentication to only the accounts within the local account DB.
i.e if no local account is present deny access/ldap auth occurring.

From looking at the options from `LDAPSearch` I'm unable to find a direct option to provide this. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Limiting based on LDAP OU is not an option based on the LDAP address structure in place.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [felix001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1325133/felix001) pointed out in the comments, the project documentation describes a flag [`AUTH_LDAP_NO_NEW_USERS`](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#auth-ldap-no-new-users):

> Prevent the creation of new users during authentication. Any users not already in the Django user database will not be able to login.

Enabling it in the settings turns the desired behaviour on:

```
# settings.py

...

AUTH_LDAP_NO_NEW_USERS = True
```

However, this feature is not contained in the currently released 1.7.0 version, so a backport is necessary. The least invasive impl I can think about is:

```
# myapp/backend.py

from django_auth_ldap import backend as ldap_backend


# backport for AUTH_LDAP_NO_NEW_USERS setting
ldap_backend.LDAPSettings.defaults.update(NO_NEW_USERS=False)


class MyLDAPBackend(ldap_backend.LDAPBackend):

    def get_or_build_user(self, username, ldap_user):
        user, built = super().get_or_build_user(username, ldap_user)
        if self.settings.NO_NEW_USERS and built:  # user was not found in local db and created instead
            raise ldap_user.AuthenticationFailed(
                f'username {username} does not exist in local DB.'
            )
        return user, built
```

Activate `AUTH_LDAP_NO_NEW_USERS` in settings and use the custom backend instead of the `LDAPBackend` for now:

```
# myapp/settings.py

AUTH_LDAP_NO_NEW_USERS = True
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS += ('myapp.backend.MyLDAPBackend',)
```

Dropping the backport is also easy: once the next version of `django-auth-ldap` is released, the only thing you will need to adapt is the `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` tuple (and of course, remove the `myapp/backend.py` module).

Comment: Thanks. However, it looks like the documentation is wrong. The link you provided shows it should be in django-auth-ldap==1.7.0. However from looking at the release notes (https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap/blob/master/CHANGES) this option is to be included in 2.0.0, which is unreleased.

Comment: @felix001 I have updated the answer with a backport proposal for the `NO_NEW_USERS` feature.

Comment: Would this work with django-python3-ldap also? It is much easier to install since it is 100 % Python code, but I haven't found how to implement this "no new users" feature with it.

Comment: @tok if I read the code of `django-python3-ldap` correctly, this isn't possible since the user is immediately saved upon creation, so refactoring of the library code is necessary. You will need to collaborate with the package author in order to implement the feature.